# Set the minimum rights or permissions for a user - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, sudo

Could you please help me to set the minimum rights or permissions to a user "test01" by editing the sudoers file `/etc/sudoers` on Ubuntu server to meet the following requirements?

1. Must not be able to enable the root user or reset the password for
   the root user.
2. Must not be able to create or delete a user or a group.
3. Must not be able to reset the password for the existing users.
4. Must not be able to access or edit the linux firewall.
5. Must not be able to access MariaDB or Apache directories, but he can just restart the MariaDB and  Apache services.
6. Must not be able to shutdown the Linux server.
7. Must be able to reboot the server and restart necessary services.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Is this a homework?

Comment: Ubuntu 8.04, it is a test server for the developer to install the Magento extensions on it.

Comment: Ubuntu 8.04 is more than 12 years old. It has reached the end of it's life and is not supported in this site. If this is not correct, please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1272112/edit) and add the new information in the question.

Comment: i edited it, i will in install ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Could you please help me to set the minimum rights or permissions to a user "test01" by editing the sudoers file "/etc/sudoers" on Ubuntu server to meet the following requirements?

Comment: Read `man sudoers`. You can configure access to a single command (beware shell escapes).